# Finding total impedance

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, impedance, reactance

I have a circuit as shown below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftFLJ0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where R1, R2 are resistors. jX1 and jX3 are reactants, and jB2 is admittance. That being said, I'm not sure how to find Zin (**Total input impedance**). I have 2 theories:

1. Convert jB2 to impedance by taking its inverse (Z = 1/Y) and find total impedance: 
   $$
   Zin = R1 + jX1 + ((R2 + jX3)||jB2)
   $$
2. Just ignore the admittance in this calculation since it's not an impedance
   $$
   Zin = R1 + jX1 + jx3 + R2
   $$

I'm not sure which one is correct. Both seem to be correct to me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For finding the total input impedance one must know where the input is (input nodes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll convert the admittance into impedance first then treat all components as resistors but always follow the correct math with the imaginary part (j). I think that's the easiest way of doing this.